# HTML table is missing the last value when extracted via Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

This code scrapes everything but the last value in the table (0 Measure). I've looked everywhere but can't understand why it's missing it. Any idea?

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

t1 = []
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'mypath/chromedriver.exe', options = options) 
driver.get("https://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/SMS")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Close']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@name='MCSearch'])[2]"))).send_keys('1605061')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@name='search'])[2]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='BASICs']/p[2]/a"))).click()
tbl = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='valueRow sumData']")))
tab = tbl.text
print(tab)
```

Comment: Even though `//tr[@class='valueRow sumData']` locates two tables in page, was able to see `0.05 measure` in the output. Try this xpath once `//table[@class='smsDetails']//tr[2]`

Comment: Running your code with few different options, I got `1.11
Measure
NOT PUBLIC
0.35
Measure
4.22
Measure
0
Measure
NOT PUBLIC
0
Measure` as an output

Comment: @cruisepandey what options do you mean? So it looks like it does pull everything in the regular mode but in the headless mode it misses the last value

Comment: No I meant there are few options args, that I have in my local, I ran the exact code what you've written, and boom it worked.

Comment: In the headless mode?

Comment: @alexb : Yes in headless mode.